Standalone application material datepicker not working in other application
Getting Provider error while trying to use the angular material datepicker from zoneless angular custom element in other application.
encounter error with provider not found.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-field',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule,MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule,MatAutocompleteModule,MatIconModule,MatButtonModule,MatInputModule,MatSelectModule],
  templateUrl: './form-field.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-field.component.scss',
})


Please edit your question and add the exact error message, to make your question more useful for future readers.

make sure you have provideNativeDateAdapter() in your your component as below
  selector: 'app-form-field',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule,MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule,MatAutocompleteModule,MatIconModule,MatButtonModule,MatInputModule,MatSelectModule],
  templateUrl: './form-field.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-field.component.scss',
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

